# Correctly optimising MySQL data for date range queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with lots of numeric data. I need to query this to get the closest row for a specific `date_added` and `name`.

My problem is that this data is not ordered by date, so when returning results I need to include `ORDER BY date_added` (or it doesn't return the correct row). Currently doing this takes a good 90 seconds to run because of this `ORDER BY` condition.

Are there any ways I can further optimise this? I've already indexed the `date_added` and `name` columns, so I'm not really sure what else can be done. I considered creating a new table with the data reordered in `date_added` order, but this isn't practical as new entries need to be added regularly.

I've stored the numeric data as decimal as it can potentially be very small, very large or both. Perhaps storing this data in a different way would be more efficient?

Comment: Please add the output of `explain select ...`

Comment: Is there any index defined on column `date_added`?

Comment: I would observe that, generally, enumerated columns can be symptomatic of poor design. 60M rows might seem like a lot, but 540M rows might actually allow for improved performance.

Comment: @FDavidov: Please read the question properly.

Comment: @juergend, oops, missed that line.

Comment: @user3420034: Looks like only the `date` index is used and not the `name` index too. Try forcing both indexes (`force index (...)`) of create a combined index.

Answer (score 0):

Add a compound index on name and date. The query above will run without using filesort.

An alternative way for the query:

```
SELECT date_added, data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4, data_5, data_6, data_7, data_8, data_9
FROM numeric_data
WHERE date_added = 
(select min(date_added) from numeric_data where date_added >= '2018-05-03 11:00:00' and name = 'aaa')
and name = 'aaa'
limit 1;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e8d89/1 .

Answer (score -1):

You can use range partitioning:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html

You need to define your partitions depends on the date range you have.

```
 CREATE TABLE `numeric_data` (
 `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `data_1` decimal(30,17) NOT NULL,
 `data_2` decimal(30,17) NOT NULL,
 `data_3` decimal(30,17) NOT NULL,
 `data_4` decimal(30,17) NOT NULL,
 `data_5` decimal(30,17) NOT NULL,
 `data_6` decimal(30,17) NOT NULL,
 `data_7` decimal(30,17) NOT NULL,
 `data_8` decimal(30,17) NOT NULL,
 `data_9` decimal(30,17) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `date_added` (`date_added`),
 KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=60000000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
      PARTITION BY RANGE( TO_DAYS(date_added) ) (
        PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2018-01-01')),
        PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2018-02-01')),
        PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2018-03-01')),
        PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2018-04-01')),
        PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
      );
```

For the below query will only use partition "future" :

```
SELECT date_added, data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4, data_5, data_6, data_7, data_8, data_9
FROM numeric_data
WHERE date_added >= '2018-05-03 11:00:00'
AND name = 'aaa'
ORDER BY date_added LIMIT 1
```